# How to change PS to (pyside2) in Powershell?

Tags: python, powershell, virtual-environment

I want to change the `PS <path>>` to `(pyside2) PS <path>>`.

I am trying to execute a command in VS Code's ternimal. But I don't know how to change PS to (pyside2) in Powershell.

Comment: looks like the activation of a Python Virtual Environment, execute the command to activate the virt env

Comment: What is "*(pyside2)*" supposed to be? Is that your virtual environment?

Comment: Do you **only** want to change how the prompt looks? Or do you **want something specific to happen**, which is the **meaning of** this change to the prompt? **Why** do you want it to happen - what *problem do you expect to solve* by having it change? Are you able to do this in other shells, such as `cmd`?

Answer (score -1):

After input the commond python -m venv  and start a powershell.The question is solved.